# Tkinter.canvas.create_window() creates two-pixel border - is it suppress it?

Tags: tkinter, canvas, width, border, createwindow

Is anybody able to advise me how to suppress 2-pixel border of an inner canvas of an outer canvas. For example - you can see the border:

```
w.mainloop()
w=tk.Tk()
f=tk.Frame(w,width=300,height=300,bg='yellow')
f.pack()
c_outer=tk.Canvas(f,width=20,height=20,bg='red')
c_outer.pack()
c_inner=tk.Canvas(c_outer,width=10,height=10,bg='blue')
c_outer.create_window(0,0,anchor=tk.NW,window=c_inner)
c_inner2=tk.Canvas(c_outer,width=10,height=10,bg='green')
c_outer.create_window(10,10,anchor=tk.NW,window=c_inner2)
```

The content of any inner canvas is circumscribed by the 2-pixed border.
Thanks for help.

Comment: If you mean the default border of the `Canvas` widget then you can remove it by setting [`highlightthickness = 0`](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.config-method)

Comment: Adding to what @Saad said, why is your `mainloop()` on top of entire code?

Answer (score 1):

`create_window` isn't adding anything. If you see a border, it's there because it's part of the widget and not because `create_window` is adding it.

Many widgets have both a border and a *highlightthickness*. The latter is for creating a ring around the widget when it has the keyboard focus.

You need to set both the `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness` to zero if you don't want any decorations around the edge of the widget.

Comment: w=tk.Tk()
    f=tk.Frame(w,width=300,height=300,bg='yellow')
    f.pack()
    c_outer=tk.Canvas(f,width=100,height=100,bg='red',borderwidth=0)
    c_outer.pack()
    c_inner=tk.Canvas(c_outer,width=10,height=10,bg='blue',highlightthickness=0)
    c_outer.create_window(0,0,anchor=tk.NW,window=c_inner)
    c_inner2=tk.Canvas(c_outer,width=10,height=10,bg='blue',highlightthickness=0)
    c_outer.create_window(10,10,anchor=tk.NW,window=c_inner2)
    w.mainloop()

Comment: @Pepa why did you post code in the comment section?